# Run script in relative path via System.cmd in elixir

Tags: command-line, elixir

I have a project with a executive file in it: `./bin/dcolors`

So, I want to run this file via `System.cmd/3`. How can I do that?

**My attempts**

First: run just `./bin/dcolors`.

```
System.cwd # => project path
System.cmd("./bin/dcolors", []) # => :enoent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [`System#cmd/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/System.html#cmd/3) states:

> `command` is expected to be an executable available in `PATH` **unless an absolute path is given**.

Since `./bin` is assumingly not on the path, one might use the absolute path, retrieved via [`System#cwd/0`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/System.html#cwd/0) and joined with the relative one using [`Path#join/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Path.html#join/2):

```
System.cwd
|> Path.join("bin/dcolors")
|> System.cmd([])
```